# Function as parameter in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reflection, async-await

I call a method containing a function:

```
public void DoMagicStuff(Func<T> anyfunction) {
  // do lots of magic stuff
}
```

This works:

```
public void DoNonAsyncStuff() {
  DoMagicStuff(()=> {
     AnotherFunction();
  }
}
```

While this does not:

```
public async Task<CustomClass> DoAsynStuff() {
   DoMagicStuff(()=> {
     return await DoSomethingDifferent();
  }
}
```

> "The await operator can only be used in async functions"

How do I make this work for async methods?

Comment: You can only await inside the delegate passed to `DoMagicStuff` if it returns a `Task` or a `Task<T>`. Yours doesn't, it only returns any old `T`

Comment: @canton7 That's not quite the issue; the lambda hasn't been decorated with the `async` keyword. Simply returning a `Task` isn't sufficient.

Comment: Ideally you need an `async` version of `DoMagicStuff` as well, because otherwise you will be forced to call `DoSomethingDifferent` synchronously, which is not good.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You're right, but it's a prerequisite

Comment: @canton7 Not necessarily; `await` can also be used in a `void` function that uses the `async` keyword. In this instance, the use of `Func<T>` will cause the lambda to be converted into a `Task`-returning function, but the return type is irrelevant to the compilation error in the question.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I know, yes. I didn't want to recommend that to OP though

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay could you elaborate on what you said, possibly providing an example? *"void function"* + *"converted into a Task"* strikes as wrong to me, but I may have misunderstood your point.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias "void function" = function that returns nothing. For the second point, when the lambda is passed as a `Func<T>` it is implicitly converted into a function that returns a `Task`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#anonymous-function-conversions

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay *"void function = function that returns nothing."* I don't think that I would agree with that. [`void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void) is a method with an explicit `void` return type IMHO. The lack of a `return` statement inside a method is not enough to make the method `void`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You're probably right about the use of `void`; an anonymous function has no return type in itself, that is determined by the delegate type it is being converted to. The point I was trying to make is that the compilation error is not related to the return type, it is due to the omission of the `async` keyword, and furthermore, that the use of `async` does not necessarily mean that a `Task` is being returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to pass asynchronous delegates to `DoMagicStuff`, then you need to overload that with an asynchronous version:

```
public void DoMagicStuff(Func<T> anyfunction)
{
    // do lots of magic stuff
    T t = anyfunction();
}

public async Task DoMagicStuff(Func<Task<T>> asyncfunction)
{
    // do lots of magic stuff
    T t = await asyncfunction();
}
```

This allows you to call `await` for the `asyncfunction`.

Any common logic can always be refactored into another method.

---

With regard to your question, `await` can only be used in a function that has been declared `async`, which your lambda hasn't.

It should be like this:

```
public async Task<CustomClass> DoAsynStuff()
{
    await DoMagicStuff(async () =>
    {
        return await DoSomethingDifferent();
    });
}
```

And in fact, because `DoSomethingDifferent` already returns a `Task`, the lambda is superfluous:

```
public async Task<CustomClass> DoAsynStuff()
{
    await DoMagicStuff(DoSomethingDifferent);
}
```

Comment: Works fine. I just had to change the method to `public async Task<T> DoMagicStuff<T>(Func<Task<T>> anyFunction)` (in addition to your suggestion)

Comment: Ok, I assumed it didn't return anything because your existing `DoMagicStuff` method is `void`.

Comment: You were kind of right. Oversimplified the code for the SO question (again)... :)